# Combining C#.Net and VTK without ActiViz.Net

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio, vtk

I have an assignment which, if I could implement it any way I wanted, would be relatively easy. Alas, there are a number of restrictions on the implementation. I need to create a Visual Studio project which uses C#.Net Windows Presentation Form (WPF) for the GUI and Visualization Toolkit (VTK) with C++ for 3D rendering. If you look that up on-line, you'll soon find something specifically designed for this--ActiViz.Net. Unfortunately, using ActiViz.Net is specifically forbidden.

I've been able to build VTK and the example projects in Visual Studio. I'm still not entirely comfortable with it, but I at least know how to do some basic rendering. WPF doesn't seem too bad on its own. But how do I combine these into a single project, with the GUI influencing the rendering? So for example, I'd use WPF to make a button that said "enlarge sphere". I'd use VTK to render a sphere, either in the same window that had the button, or in a separate window. When the user clicks the button, it will run an event method in C#. And that method will somehow tell the C++ code using VTK to make the sphere larger.

At the moment, I'm not even sure how to make a single project with both of these parts, let alone how to communicate between them. Really, the best I can think of right now is two separate programs, with the GUI program launching the 3D program, and influencing the rendering by writing out a file that the rendering program reads. Not very elegant, I know. Any better ideas?

Comment: Well WPF already has 3D built-in (including shaders) so why use _"ActiViz.Net"_?   In saying that there are alot of articles here on how to call c/c++ from c#.  Look for "p-invoke"

Comment: I'd love to do that, but the assignment specifically says to use VTK for the 3D rendering, not what's built into WPF. Not being able to use ActiViz.Net, which the maker of VTK made for .Net integration, makes it even harder.